# Use lazyload.js on a container loaded by jquery .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to implement lazyload.js on an e-commerce website written in C#, ASP.net.
I managed (with help from the community, thanks by the way) to correctly set up the plugin for the product listing but I also have a "live search box" that loads the listings from a .apsx page via ajax .load() method. 
The problem is lazy load won't work in the results container. I've tried every setting but still no luck. The result page from witch I load the results container has lazy load implemented and works, but in my ajax loaded container the images just don't replace.

This is the code to load the search results (#srs is the container holding the product listing on the search page):

```
$(".search-box-inner").keyup(function(){
var uType=$(this).val();
uType=uType.replace(/\ /g, '%20');
var myLength = $(this).val().length;
var url="SearchLive.aspx?SearchTerm=";
var div="#srs";
if((myLength>=3)){
    $("#search-results").slideDown("slow");
    $("#search-results").load(url+uType+' '+div);
    $(".searchbox-spinner").fadeIn("slow");
    setTimeout( "$('.searchbox-spinner').fadeOut();",1000 );
}
if(myLength<2){
    $("#search-results").slideUp("slow");
}
});
```

This is the code to generate the images to be lazy loaded:

```
<asp:Image ID="imagePath" class="lazy" height="100px"  data-original='<%#Utilities.GetImageUrl(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.FullImagePath").ToString(), true)%>' src="http://placehold.it/100x100" runat="server" AlternateText='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Name")%>' />
```

I've tried some stuff but didn't manage to break trough. 
Please help...

Comment: how do you call lazyload? since the results get dynamically loaded via load() and lazyload gets initialised after dom ready, i assume, that it doesn't work, because lazy load doesn't know the new images. have you tried, to additional call lazyload inside the load callback?

Comment: Yes, I have tried calling it inside the function with no luck.

Comment: Now I'm embarrassed... `$("#search-results").load(url+uType+' '+div, function() {
   console.log("Loading stuff");
   $("img.lazy").show().lazyload();//lazy init
  });` ... did the trick:)

Comment: @errand this works but I still got a problem: the plugin reacts to the scroll event on the page, but does not react to the scroll event on the container. It just loads the first visible images but doesn't load the rest on scroll unless I scroll down the entire page. My container is absolutely positioned with a given height of 60vh (I've tried with a fixed height also) and I have passed the option `container:$("#search-results")` to the function...

Comment: @errand solved it by adding `$("#search-results").scroll(function(){
    $("img.lazy").show().lazyload()
   });` at the end of my load() function.

Comment: perfect ;) u can post it as solution by yourself and mark it as solved - since it may help others - and you've found out all by yourself. greetings*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by adding

```
$("#search-results").scroll(function(){ 
$("img.lazy").show().lazyload() 
});
```

at the end of my load() function.

So, if **lazy load** missbehaves when used in a container that is not part of the page (aka a absolute or fixed positioned container that has a scroll of its own and doesn't trigger the lazy loading on images on scroll), you can manually trigger it by initilalising the lazy load plugin inside the container's scroll function.

```
$("#your-container").scroll(function(){
$("img.lazy").show().lazyload() 
});
```